# Pandas unpivot dataframe using datetime elements from column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

[image: original dataframe]

Here `Store` serves as id, `Jan 18 - Mar 18` columns represent sales of said stores in respective years and months and `Trading Area` is an example of time-invariant feature of a store.

For simplicity assume sales column names are already converted to proper datetime format.

Expected result:

[image: transformed dataframe]

I was thinking about using `pandas.melt`, however I'm not sure how to properly use datetime information contained within column names to construct columns for year and month (obviously this can be done manually in a loop but I need to apply this to arbitrarily large dataframes and this is where it gets tedious, surely a more elegant solution exists).

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: `data = pd.DataFrame({'Store':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Jan 18':[100, 50, 60], 'Feb 18':[120, 70, 80], 'Mar 18':[140, 90, 100], 'Trading Area':[500, 800, 700]})`

Comment: Could you add a copy of your data that can be copied into a text editor?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo please check the edit

Comment: How do you arrive at your original dataframe? In other words, depending on how you load this data, there could be an easier solution than massaging after the fact.

Comment: @mayosten I receive it as is, not my call unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) in the following way:

```
# melt
melted = data.melt(id_vars=['Store', 'Trading Area'], var_name='Month', value_name='Sales')

# extract month and year
melted[['Month', 'Year']] = melted.Month.str.split(expand=True)

# format year
melted['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(melted.Year, yearfirst=True, format='%y').dt.year

print(melted.sort_values('Store'))
```

**Output**

```
  Store  Trading Area Month  Sales  Year
0     A           500   Jan    100  2018
3     A           500   Feb    120  2018
6     A           500   Mar    140  2018
1     B           800   Jan     50  2018
4     B           800   Feb     70  2018
7     B           800   Mar     90  2018
2     C           700   Jan     60  2018
5     C           700   Feb     80  2018
8     C           700   Mar    100  2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `wide_to_long` followed by a `stack`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df=data,
                stubnames=['Jan','Feb', 'Mar'],
                i=['Store','Trading Area'],
                j='Year',
                sep=' '
               )
   .stack()
   .reset_index(name='Sales')
   .rename(columns={'level_3':'Month'})
)
```

Output:

```
  Store  Trading Area  Year Month  Sales
0     A           500    18   Jan    100
1     A           500    18   Feb    120
2     A           500    18   Mar    140
3     B           800    18   Jan     50
4     B           800    18   Feb     70
5     B           800    18   Mar     90
6     C           700    18   Jan     60
7     C           700    18   Feb     80
8     C           700    18   Mar    100
```