# How to read the data in Pandas's dataframe row wise and plot the values as a timeseries if column represents months and index is years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have one data frame which has months as a column and first column represents year. I want to plot the time-Series of this data frame i.e. reading each row and plotting a timeseries.
I am providing a small part of my data frame below.
Kindly let me know any way to perform this task.

YEAR    JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC

0   1870    -0.02   -0.02   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01

1   1871    -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   -0.01   0.00    0.00    0.00

and So on....

Comment: This answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598236/4611565 should help as a start ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you store your data in a pandas DataFrame in a form as follows(each row represents one year):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1870,0.02,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01],
                             [1871,0.02,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01]]),
                   columns =  ["YEAR", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"])
```

Which outputs df in this way:

```
     YEAR   JAN   FEB   MAR   APR   MAY  ...   JUL   AUG   SEP   OCT   NOV   DEC
0  1870.0  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  ...  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
1  1871.0  0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01  0.01  ...  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
[2 rows x 13 columns]
```

This is just a two-year sample with duplicate row entries.

What you need is something like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cols = np.array(df.columns)[1:]
rows_size= df.shape[0]
x = np.empty((1, 0), str)
y = np.empty((1, 0), float)
for i in range (rows_size):
        x = np.append(x, str(int(df.iloc[i, 0]))+ "-" + cols.reshape(1,12) , axis = 1)
        y = np.append(y, np.array(df.iloc[i, 1:]).reshape(1,12), axis = 1)
x = x.reshape(-1)
y = y.reshape(-1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x,x, rotation ='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.2)
plt.show()
```

the resulting plot would be then something like: [image: (image)]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I want the plot in the same manner. Actually I am beginner in Python. Could you please explain me the key concept of your solution . So that I can understand your approach in more clearer way.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll go deep in code line by line:

Comment: line1: import a library to plot
line2: I get the column values of your DataFrame object, df, convert it to numpy array and return all but the very first one(which indicates year)
line3: Store the number of rows in variable rows_size
line 4: x is a preserved empty numpy variable. I get the size of 1 because when you use append in line7, you require x to be of the same first-axis shape with what it appends to.
line 5: I'll do the same thing for y. x is of type float. but x is of type str, because x records the x-axis ticks

Comment: line6:   I iterate over rows_size to get each row and obtain the new x and y
line7: str(int(df.iloc[i, 0])) returns the year of the current row. I concatenate it to colls with a given shape, then append it to x across axis = 1(axis =0 indicates the first axis, in contrast)
line8: do the same thing for y
line 9 and 10 reshapes them back to one-dimensional array. Prior to these 2 lines, x and y were 2-dimensional.
line 10: I set the ticks for x to be x itself, and rotate ticks to be vertical, so that they wouldn't overlap

Comment: line 11: a little bit of space from the bottom so that the ticks wont go out of the plot frame

Comment: Great...thank you very much for such a good explanation.